# software for HPC cluster management

Tags: software-recommendation, cluster

We have a small cluster of about 40 nodes running RHEL 6. This cluster is managed using rocks which is convenient. To shut down the nodes, all I do is:

```
 rocks run host halt
```

I can also install software to all the nodes, manage users etc very easily. We are looking to upgrade this using ubuntu 22 since RHEL6 is too old. I noticed there is openHPC but there are no binaries of it for ubuntu. So my question is what equivalent software are available for ubuntu for this?

goals:

1. Provisioning of OS
2. shutting down nodes
3. Installing software
4. managing and synching users

Comment: I didn't ask multiple questions. thank you for being so welcoming!